# comparing float values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am getting undesired result when I compare dataframe column (which is float in nature) with float value. My dataframe looks like:

```
df
    Measurement      Year   checking
0   4.478861e-04    2015    less
1   4.478861e-04    2015    less
2   4.478861e-04    2015    less
3   4.478861e-04    2015    less
4   4.478861e-04    2015    less
5   4.478861e-04    2015    less
6   4.478861e-04    2015    less
7   4.478861e-04    2015    less
8   6.337777        2015    greater
9   8.903316        2015    greater
10  9.317186        2015    greater
```

Datatype of dataframe is

```
Measurement    float64
Year             int64
checking        object
dtype: object
```

When I filter the dataframe using following code:

```
df[df['Measurement']> 5.69]
```

It returns empty dataframe. Similarly, when I tried the comparison using loop using following code:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
   if df.iloc[i,'Measurement'] > 5.69:
      print('Comparison is true')
```

It did not print the statement when value was greater than 5.69. Could anyone guide why the code is behaving abnormally?

Answer (score 0):

`df[df['Measurement']> 5.69]` seems to work for me with the dataframe, I have added the snippet. and have added the `for` loop with the if condition also.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Measurement': [4.478861e-04, 4.478861e-04, 4.478861e-04, 6.337777, 8.903316],
    'Year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015],
    'checking': ['less', 'less', 'less', 'greater', 'greater']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("DataFrame:")
print(df)

result = df.dtypes

print("\nDatatypes:")
print(result)

print("\nMeasurement:")
print(df[df['Measurement']> 5.69])

measurement = df['Measurement']

print("\nMeasurements greater than 5.69:")
for x in measurement:
    if x > 5.69:
        print(x)
```

Output:

```
DataFrame:
   Measurement  Year checking
0     0.000448  2015     less
1     0.000448  2015     less
2     0.000448  2015     less
3     6.337777  2015  greater
4     8.903316  2015  greater

Datatypes:
Measurement    float64
Year             int64
checking        object
dtype: object

Measurement:
   Measurement  Year checking
3     6.337777  2015  greater
4     8.903316  2015  greater

Measurements greater than 5.69:
6.337777
8.903316
```

Comment: don't know. Your code snippet working fine now. However, my old code still behaving the same

Comment: My dataframe is deriving from some calculation. May be calculation might be causing the issue